# FFMPEG sepia filter

Tags: video, ffmpeg

Can't seem to figure out why my colorchannelmixer filter is not working with ffmpeg. It doesn't appear to output any errors, but the ouput.mp4 video is just a 0 second long video with no thumbnail.

Here's the command I'm trying.

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -filter_complex \
"[0:v] colorchannelmixer=.393:.769:.189:0:.349:.686:.168:0:.272:.534:.131[f1];\
[f1] eq=1.0:0:1.3:2.4:1.0:1.0:1.0:1.0 [outv]" -map "[outv]" output.mp4
```

And the output I receive.

```
ffmpeg version 2.8.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
      built with gcc 5.2.0 (GCC)
      configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
      libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
      libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
      libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
      libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
      libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
      libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
      libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
      libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
    Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'video.mp4':
      Metadata:
        major_brand     : mp42
        minor_version   : 1
        compatible_brands: mp41mp42isom
        creation_time   : 2017-04-18 20:22:52
      Duration: 00:00:59.20, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 5045 kb/s
        Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 2 kb/s (default)
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 2017-04-18 20:22:52
          handler_name    : Core Media Audio
        Stream #0:1(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 5038 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 2017-04-18 20:22:52
          handler_name    : Core Media Video
    File 'output.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
    No pixel format specified, yuv444p for H.264 encoding chosen.
    Use -pix_fmt yuv420p for compatibility with outdated media players.
    [libx264 @ 04f1b8e0] using SAR=1/1
    [libx264 @ 04f1b8e0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 AVX2 LZCNT BMI2
    [libx264 @ 04f1b8e0] profile High 4:4:4 Predictive, level 4.0, 4:4:4 8-bit
    [libx264 @ 04f1b8e0] 264 - core 148 r2638 7599210 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2015 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=4 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
    Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4':
      Metadata:
        major_brand     : mp42
        minor_version   : 1
        compatible_brands: mp41mp42isom
        encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
        Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv444p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
        Metadata:
          encoder         : Lavc56.60.100 libx264
    Stream mapping:
      Stream #0:1 (h264) -> colorchannelmixer
      eq -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
    Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
    frame=   50 fps=4.7 q=-1.0 Lsize=     281kB time=00:00:01.92 bitrate=1197.3kbits/s
    video:279kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.502929%
    [libx264 @ 04f1b8e0] frame I:1     Avg QP:19.00  size: 51169
    [libx264 @ 04f1b8e0] frame P:13    Avg QP:20.60  size: 10882
    [libx264 @ 04f1b8e0] frame B:36    Avg QP:23.29  size:  2572
    [libx264 @ 04f1b8e0] consecutive B-frames:  2.0%  4.0%  6.0% 88.0%
    [libx264 @ 04f1b8e0] mb I  I16..4: 25.5% 63.4% 11.1%
    [libx264 @ 04f1b8e0] mb P  I16..4:  2.7%  2.8%  0.2%  P16..4: 22.7%  5.4%  2.7%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:63.5%
    [libx264 @ 04f1b8e0] mb B  I16..4:  0.3%  0.5%  0.0%  B16..8: 17.2%  0.7%  0.0%  direct: 0.1%  skip:81.1%  L0:43.6% L1:55.1% BI: 1.4%
    [libx264 @ 04f1b8e0] 8x8 transform intra:58.3% inter:91.1%
    [libx264 @ 04f1b8e0] coded y,u,v intra: 25.2% 10.1% 12.0% inter: 2.7% 0.5% 0.6%
    [libx264 @ 04f1b8e0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 44% 36% 13%  8%
    [libx264 @ 04f1b8e0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 22% 20% 42%  3%  2%  2%  4%  3%  3%
    [libx264 @ 04f1b8e0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 29% 26% 12%  4%  6%  6%  9%  5%  3%
    [libx264 @ 04f1b8e0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
    [libx264 @ 04f1b8e0] ref P L0: 61.3%  6.1% 22.1% 10.5%
    [libx264 @ 04f1b8e0] ref B L0: 78.5% 16.8%  4.6%
    [libx264 @ 04f1b8e0] ref B L1: 94.9%  5.1%
    [libx264 @ 04f1b8e0] kb/s:1140.95
```

Comment: The console shows 50 frames encoded, albeit in YUV 4:4:4. Does this show up in players? Can you share the input?

Comment: Yeah, it was an encoding issue. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem. My problem was that video was generated but not supported to play on mobile devices. I solved it by changing `-vcodec libx264` to `-vcodec mpeg4`
The final command become: `"-threads 2 -y -i" + initialFile + "-strict experimental -filter_complex  [0:v]colorchannelmixer=.393:.769:.189:0:.349:.686:.168:0:.272:.534:.131[colorchannelmixed];[colorchannelmixed]eq=1.0:0:1.3:2.4:1.0:1.0:1.0:1.0[color_effect] -map [color_effect] -map 0:a -vcodec mpeg4 -crf 23 -b:v 1000K -maxrate 1500K -bufsize 500K" + resultFile;`